# Firestore storage size limit how to store large arrays

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got a collection `users/$userID/followers` this user ID is the firebase UID so is 29 bytes long (  String sizes are calculated as the number of UTF-8 encoded bytes + 1.)

Inside each user document i got a array named followers and another named following. Both arrays contain a lot of userID's so here's the problem.

In firestore each document has a max size of 1mb so it's easy to see I'm gonna run out of space soon. My question is what's the best way to manage large arrays like this ones.

Most obvious option: Create another document, containing just a pair of new arrays to continue saving this data ( and do this in a recursive way when the limit of the document is reached).

So some better idea? Or at least how to simplify the process a little bit.

More info about size limits here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size?hl=en-419

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I solved it just creating new docs. As Doug Stevenson says there is a cost to scalability.

Comment: So you are denormalising

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about the size of an array, you should instead split each item out of the array and make it its own document.  This is the only way you will achieve massive scalability with Firestore for storing many individual items.

Yes, it will cost more. There is a cost to scalability.

Comment: The read costs will be astronomical if these documents are being called multiple times. You pay for each read.

Comment: @OliverDixon In Google Cloud's nam5 region, 100,000 document reads costs $.06. You'll have to read a **lot** of documents to get "astronomical" billing.

Comment: 100,000 document reads is nothing if you have even 1000 users. I have apps with over 1 billion reads, and they are only around 60-70k users with careful planning not to read too much.

Comment: @OliverDixon  But still not "astronomical", especially if you model data and  deal with your local cache effectively. Kind of an overstatement.